# My site won't open in IE. It opens fine in Chrome and Firefox. Any ideas?

Tags: internet-explorer

I've made a website using wordpress and a theme called Headway, plus a few plugins. It looks great and works great on FF and Chrome, but then when I go to open it on IE... nothing. It loads half the page and then freezes. I've asked the guys at Headway, but they say it's some script error. I don't know how to check or find out what particular thing on my site is stopping IE from opening it. I've tried the W3 HTML validator, but as I'm not a coder I have no idea!

Would anyone mind having a quick look and telling me what my site's issue is?
It's http://yasta.pr

Thanks ever so much!

Eleanor

PS. I'd be willing to pay someone if they could spend the time to figure out what the problem was and then help me fix it! :)

Comment: Which IE? Which FF? Which Chrome? See, there are **crucial** differences between IE6, IE8, IE9, FF3.5, FF4, and Chrome whatever-version-it-has-this-minute. Adding the OS and Flash version might also be helpful. The browser version should be somewhere like "Help -> About" or similar. (BTW it looks okay in Opera 11 on Ubuntu Linux 10.04.2)

Comment: Run your site through the W3 validator -- http://validator.w3.org/ .  I get 80 errors and 69 warnings.  W3 compliance doesn't guarantee it'll work under IE, of course, since IE is the least "compatible" of the bunch, but eliminating obvious errors can't hurt.

Comment: (There's also http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ for CSS validation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is: The problem was with the Digg Digg plugin :-) (answered in comments :-))

Answer (score 0):

Try using [**Firebug**](http://getfirebug.com/), it's a tool-plugin that works with FireFox.

I will help you debug the webpage.

Firebug JavaScript debugging tutorials:

[Script Tab : Javascript Debugging](http://michaelsync.net/2007/09/30/firebug-tutorial-script-tab-javascript-debugging)
[Logging, Profiling and CommandLine (Part I)](http://michaelsync.net/2007/09/09/firebug-tutorial-logging-profiling-and-commandline-part-i)

Comment: @Piskvor - the IE i'm looking at it on is version 8, 64-bit edition. But I've been told by others that it doesn't load on any IE.
@Daniel R Hicks - did that, but what with me being a bit stupid in these things, I have no idea how to fix them - i built the site on wordpress, but i'll check it out again and see if i can figure anything out from what it gives me.
@BurnAfterReading - I'm going to take that as a compliment! ;)

Comment: I tried using Firebug, but I don't fully understand everything it's showing me.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is likely the xmlHttpRequest.

IE builds a different object for the same purpose then FF or Chrome.

```
try { 
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
} catch (e) { 
    try { 
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
    } catch (E) { 
        xmlhttp = false; 
    } 
} 

if  (!xmlhttp && typeof  XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined' ) { 
    try  { 
        xmlhttp = new  XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } catch  (e) { 
        xmlhttp = false ; 
    } 
}
```

You might be using AJAX in order to load the content of the page, which requires the above code in order to properly create the object for the response in all browsers.

Comment: Hi José. I'm not using AJAX to load page content, but I suppose it might be there in a plugin. Any ideas as to how I can find out what's causing the problem?

Comment: I'd be willing to pay someone if they could find exactly what the problem was and help me fix it! :)

Comment: @Eleanor - The plugin 'tubepress_pro_2_2_0' is firing off an AJAX request. This could be the problem....

Comment: @Jamie - thankyou. So, does that mean that inserting the above code from José would work? And if so, where do i put it? And yes yes I know I'm a total noob... sorry all.. :)

Comment: Start by disabling some of the plugins first and see if it loads in IE :-) If it's a problem with a plugin, we can go from there.

Comment: I also see you have a cache, could you disable it?

Comment: Hey Jamie - I have no cache. I did have a caching plugin installed before, but deleted it. I'm going to go plugin by plugin and see if I can figure out what's causing the issue...

Comment: @Eleanor - Which plugin have you just disabled? Works now on IE....the image slider plugin I assume?

Comment: Hey - I disabled them all and put them back one by one. Turns out it was Digg Digg, which I don't overly need anyway, so I think we might be done here... You are a star, thankyou so much!

Comment: You're very welcome. You can mark my answer (above or below) as the chosen one if you like :-) thanks! good luck with your site. :-)

Answer (score -2):

Please reset your IE Settings => Internet Options => Reset

This has been my savior